# How can I recalibrate quick look window?

Tags: quicklook

I have this issue where quick look window is away from its default position

[image: quick look]

I know I can drag it back, but is there a way to just resume its default position?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I can drag it back, but is there a way to just resume it default position?

One way that I know of, without dragging the *window* back, is to in **Terminal** use the `killall Finder` *command*.

This works for me in **macOS Catalina**.